# Is it possible to take an image from a UIWebView and display it natively without reloading?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

Say I load a webpage with an image on it. Is there a way to reuse this loaded image within a `UIImageView` without reloading the image from a url?

Answer (score 2):

If the image is cached by [URL loading system](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html), it will come from the cache when you try to load it.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I can't give a large explanation as im on y phone but I feel like what your looking for is 'core data store' there are several examples of how to use this framework, but it's quite complicated and has a large learning curve with ios development.

Also you say 'a' uiwebview. Does that mean that the URL your accessing to show within your uiwebview is static? If so, just copy and save the image and store the image in your project for future reference.

Or are you allowing the user to keep swapping through links in the uiwebview and store all those images that popup on the web page?

Sorry I'm just unclear with the question... Please no down votes :)